# Records in AD for SCCM

Tags: windows, active-directory, sccm, sms

I'm replacing an SCCM box and new clients are still looking for the old server. So my question is this: What records (NOT client side) exist for SCCM to work? Wins? AD? I need to check each one to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCCM clients, even after being pointed to the new SCCM server, will often look to an old distribution point, if the records exist in WINS and AD.  In WINS the `SMS_SLP` record should be updated with the New SCCM Server address.  Also the following records should be deleted in AD in the System, System Management folder:

```
SMS-Site-<OLD Site Code>
SMS-MP-<OLD Site Code>
SMS-SLP-<OLD Site Code>
SMS-<OLD Site Code>
```

The records above should be in AD for you NEW SCCM server for everything to work correctly.